# Error in union two different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How i can combine two queries in SQL Server 2008, when i use this query :

```
SELECT DATE,
       SHIFT,
       QTY,
       JUDUL
FROM
(
    SELECT B.BASEREF AS PO,
           A.DOCDATE AS DATE,
           A.U_SOL_SHIFT AS SHIFT,
           SUM(B.QUANTITY) AS QTY,
           'FG' AS JUMLAH
    FROM OIGN A
         INNER JOIN IGN1 B ON A.DOCENTRY = B.DOCENTRY
         INNER JOIN OWOR C ON B.BASEREF = C.DOCNUM
    WHERE A.DOCDATE >= [%0]
          AND A.DOCDATE <= [%1]
          AND B.ITEMCODE = C.ITEMCODE
    GROUP BY A.DOCDATE,
             A.U_SOL_SHIFT,
             B.BASEREF
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.BASEREF AS PO,
           A.DOCDATE AS DATE,
           A.U_SOL_SHIFT AS SHIFT,
           SUM(B.QUANTITY) AS QTY,
           'WASTE' AS JUMLAH
    FROM OIGN A
         INNER JOIN IGN1 B ON A.DOCENTRY = B.DOCENTRY
         INNER JOIN OWOR C ON B.BASEREF = C.DOCNUM
    WHERE A.DOCDATE >= [%0]
          AND A.DOCDATE <= [%1]
          AND B.ITEMCODE <> C.ITEMCODE
    GROUP BY A.DOCDATE,
             A.U_SOL_SHIFT,
             B.BASEREF
) B;
```

i get error message like this :

```
1). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. 
2). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
```

Comment: What are `[%0]` and `[%1]` meant to be?  The `[` and `]` look very out of place...  *(Basic debugging practice would be to make the smaller parts of the whole work.  So, try to fix and validate just One of the queries before you try to get the `UNION ALL` working.)*

Comment: The error complains about `AND`, not UNION, probably `[%0] AND`. This isn't valid syntax. If you want to pass parameters use `@paramname`.

Comment: [%0] and [%1] its working when i use one queries, but its error when i combine them with this format query "Select * from (query 1 union query 2)"

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the following approach. It is not equivalent query, however, it shows all the information as the original one. However, instead of showing the quantities in a separate row it shows them in one row.

```
SELECT  
    B.BASEREF AS PO,
    A.DOCDATE AS DATE,
    A.U_SOL_SHIFT AS SHIFT,
    SUM(case when B.ITEMCODE=C.ITEMCODE then B.QUANTITY end) AS FG_QTY,
    SUM(case when B.ITEMCODE!=C.ITEMCODE then B.QUANTITY end) AS WASTE_QTY,
FROM    
    OIGN A 
    INNER JOIN IGN1 B ON A.DOCENTRY=B.DOCENTRY
    INNER JOIN OWOR C ON B.BASEREF=C.DOCNUM
WHERE   
    A.DOCDATE>= [%0] AND A.DOCDATE<=[%1] 
GROUP BY    
    A.DOCDATE,
    A.U_SOL_SHIFT,
    B.BASEREF
```

`[%0]` a `[%1]` seems odd. Technicaly it is interpreted as a reference to an object named `%0` or `%1`, which is probably not what have you intended. Did you mean to use some values or variables instead?